# what's the difference between model->alias and model->name in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

`alias` and `name` are both properties in cake models. They seem to be similar, but since both of them exist, there must be a difference. What is it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing, but an alias could be the assigned value when you have a relationship between a model and another and you give the associated model a name not equal to that of the class.

For example:

```
$hasMany = array('UserNew' => array('className' => 'User'));
```

In that case, you're using the model that's actually called User, but you're referencing it as 'UserNew'.

Comment: $hasMany = array('Friend' => array('className' => 'User')); would have be a better example, but you are correct. :)

Because of this, you want to use `alias` where possible, since you can never be sure that `name` is actually the object you think you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

It's a collection of table aliases used when cake does a join.  From `cake/lib/model/model_php5.php`:

```
/**
 * Alias table names for model, for use in SQL JOIN statements.
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    var $alias = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporarily change the table in a model, and you're overriding the CakePHP magic FROM , change $this->alias to what you want it called. $this->name seems to be used in the constructor and must build the alias somewhere in that process. Changing $this->name in a method you want to override, is not enough. You'll have to change $this->alias and perform the method setSource() as in below:

```
function my_override_method(){
  $this->setSource('new_db_table_name_here');
  $this->alias = "NewTable";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `name`: The name of the model, for example `Post`.
- `alias`: The alias of the model, this is used for registering the instance in the `ClassRegistry`, for example `ParentThread`.

[Model::__construct( )](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#___construct)

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275154/what-is-cakephp-model-alias-used-for) question also.