# Cakephp model alias works, but view doesn't show

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

I read your answer about [cakephp model alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275154/what-is-cakephp-model-alias-used-for) and I did on my model what you wrote, I debuged my view and it list what I want, but it doesn't show the list on the respective field, do you have any idea what is wrong?

My model:

```
'ResponsavelManutencao' => array(
      'className' => 'Operador',
      'foreignKey' => 'responsavel_manutencao_id',
      'conditions' => '',
      'fields' => '',
      'order' => '')
```

My controller:

```
function add(
      $responsavelManutencao = $this->Dentista->ResponsavelManutencao->find('list');
      $this->set(compact('responsavelManutencao'));)
```

My view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('responsavel_relacionamento_id', array(
      'class' => 'field text small', 'empty' => '',
      'after' => 'Funcionario responsavel por manter o contato comercial.')); 
      debug($responsavelRelacionamento);
```

Comment: you are using first responsavel_manutencao and in the view responsavelRelacionamento ??  the autofill usually works if you have it in $this->data

Comment: Sorry api55, i paste the wrong code, but nanoman answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong with the CakePHP singular/plural rules for your language. I think you should name your view variable "responsavelRelacionamentos" for it to work.

However, the safest way to accomplish your goal without inflection magic would be:

```
echo $this->Form->input('responsavel_relacionamento_id', array(
    'options' => $responsavelRelacionamento,
    'class' => 'field text small', 'empty' => '',
    'after' => 'Funcionario responsavel por manter o contato comercial.'
));
```