# How to correctly use cakephp model alias

Tags: cakephp, model, alias

If you were so kind to provide some basic code showing how correctly use a model alias.

My main confusion is on

1. When i use an alias for a model, should i create especific controllers and views for such alias just as when i use a model for which i create specific controllers and views or should i use aliases as simple extensions of existing models?
2. Please provide an example of alias usage in a controller.

I am sorry i am not providing any code, but my confusion is at a very abstract and schematic level.

Comment: What problem are you going to solve?

Comment: Internal messaging system for a website. I have a model but obviously the fact it has multiple foreignKeys to my User model is making it hard for me to implement, I have seen examples and aliases is the way to go, I am just confused on how they actually should be used. It's pretty ignorant from my part but the documentation and code explaining it is very scarce. Help

Comment: The similar question has already been answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275154/what-is-cakephp-model-alias-used-for

Answer (score 4):

1. No, you don't need to create a controller and views for the aliased model
2. Consider the eg. of messages table which has foreign keys sender_id and recipient_id which both point to the users model. So in your Message model the association declaration would look something like this:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'sender_id'
        ),
        'Recipient' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        )
    );
```

In your messages controller if you want to access the Sender then you use `$this->Message->Sender` or for recipient `$this->Message->Recipient`. If you do a find on Message model then the resulting array will have sender(s) under 'Sender' and recipient(s) under 'Recipient' key respectively.